# How Can I Add Two Buttons In A Row Of ListView Without Overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I want to make a app like that custom layout ScreenShot:[image]  .This is one row and I add like that row 100 more.So the people can clik number or its information(`i`).

But it is shown like that : [image] two buttons overlapping .But I want two button next to each other it is like that in custom_layout.xml(you can see screen shot).

This is my `custom_layout.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="87dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="317dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="87dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="162dp"
            android:layout_height="424dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="87dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And this is my `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.hey.task.attendancesystem;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button[] button=new Button[15];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        //listeyi customlayouttaki şekilde oluşturdum hepsini
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            }
        });

    }


    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return button.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);
            Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
            Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

            for (int j = 0;j<15;j++)
                button1.setText(i + "");

            for (int j = 0;j<15;j++)
                button2.setText("i");

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i get your question but you can simply use LinearLayout with weight. eg:-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5" // or whatever you want
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Title 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5" // or whatever you want
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Title 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linear layout with a `android:weightSum=""` attribute in place of constraint layout in your custom_layout.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"/>

<Button
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`weightSum` attribute is useful for having the layout rendered correctly for any device, which will not happen if you set width and height directly.